# npm install won't install the correct packages

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

I have a package.json file that installs all the correct packages on one system fine, but not another.

Working system:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.10
Node: 12.20.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.12
... compiler-cli, core, forms, language-service, localize
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.10
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.10
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.10
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.10
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.10
@angular/animations               9.1.11
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/cli                      9.1.10
@angular/common                   9.1.11
@angular/compiler                 9.1.11
@angular/http                     7.2.16
@angular/material                 9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.10
@schematics/angular               9.1.10
@schematics/update                0.901.10
rxjs                              6.6.3
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.43.0
```

System that isn't working

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.1
Node: 14.15.5
OS: win32 ia32

Angular: 7.2.16
... animations, common, core, forms, http, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.13.8
@angular-devkit/core            7.3.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      9.1.15
@angular/cdk                    9.1.3
@angular/cli                    9.1.15
@angular/compiler               9.1.13
@angular/compiler-cli           9.1.13
@angular/language-service       7.2.15
@angular/localize               9.1.12
@angular/material               7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                7.3.8
@schematics/angular             9.1.15
@schematics/update              0.901.15
rxjs                            6.6.0
typescript                      3.2.4
webpack                         4.40.2
```

The non-working system has an global Angular version of  11.2.1 but the local version comes out at 7.2.16

Why???

Notice the @angular-devkit/core is different from the two systems even though they use the same package files.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your `npm version`? npm version 7.x have breaking changes which might be causing the issue for you. if so, you can try using `npm i -g npm@6`

Comment: This was the issue.   

npm version 7.6.2

I have a 12.20.2 version of Node and was able to run the npm from that directory (v 6.14.11) and install ran fine. 

THanks!